# Downloading an attachment from Trello cards

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, trello

I am trying to download all the attachments from my cards on a Trello board using `py-trello`.

Here is the sample code (private information removed):

```
from trello import TrelloClient
import requests

personal_token = ''
account_token = ''

client = TrelloClient(api_key=personal_token, api_secret=account_token)

board = client.get_board('')

cards = board.all_cards()
for card in cards:
    for attachment in card.get_attachments():
        response = requests.get(attachment.url)

        if response.status_code == 200:
               with open(attachment.name, 'wb') as file:
                   file.write(response.content)
        else:
            print(response.status_code, response.text)
    
        break
    break
```

The issue is that I get `401 Unauthorised` error when I try to get the URL using `requests`. I've tried adding basic auth like so:

```
basic = HTTPBasicAuth(personal_token, account_token)
```

Same issue. I've also tried adding it to the URL like so:

```
url = f'{url}?key={personal_token}&token={account_token}'
```

But it also fails. I had a look at the `py-trello` code but I wasn't able to easily see if it has a download attachment function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is the tokens have to be sent in a header. The filename has to be gotten from the url as well.

Here is the updated code:

```
from trello import TrelloClient
import requests

personal_token = ''
account_token = ''

client = TrelloClient(api_key=personal_token, api_secret=account_token)

board = client.get_board('')

headers = {
    "Authorization": f'OAuth oauth_consumer_key="{personal_token}", oauth_token="{account_token}"'
}

cards = board.all_cards()
for card in cards:
    for attachment in card.get_attachments():
        response = requests.get(attachment.url)
        file_name = attachment.url.split('/')[-1]

        if response.status_code == 200:
               with open(file_name, 'wb') as file:
                   file.write(response.content)
        else:
            print(response.status_code, response.text)
    
        break
    break
```